# VBA Sum value with condition > 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that sums my items if it finds NOMINAL_MAX. However, I would like to add a condition > 0. when i add it i get a "Type mismatch" error. How to fix it ?

```
With wbMe.Worksheets("pochodne")
WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA = "WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA"
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
            .Range("T35").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column) > 0)
        Else
            SumCriteria = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: That looks like a case for `SUMIF`, also a WorksheetFunction

Comment: @CIAndrews I added SumIf instead of Sum, but it shows that "Arguments not optional"

Comment: Please, replace `...Sum(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column) > 0` with `SumIf(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), ">0")`. `SumIf` needs a second parameters, which should be separated by comma. In case of such a condition, it must be supplied as string (between double quotes)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sumif` in this way:

```
With Worksheets("pochodne")
    WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA = "WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA"
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
        .Range("T35").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), ">0")
    Else
        SumCriteria = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
  End With
```

Comment: Thanks CIA its working